# imagecreatefromjpeg($file_name): failed to open stream

Tags: php, wordpress, image-processing, watermark

Hello everyone I am trying to add watermark to the uploaded images in WordPressbut when I use `imagecreatefromjpeg($file_name)` it throws this warning

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg('file_name'): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized.

Here is the code I am using.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'adding_watermark', 20);

function adding_watermark() {
global $product;
$id = get_the_ID();
$name = get_the_title();
$link = get_the_permalink();
$padding = 3;
$opacity = 100;

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($link);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($image);
exit;
$watermark = imagestring($image, 1, 5, 5, 'TEST', '#fff');
$image_size = getimagesize($image);
$dest_x = $image_size[0] - $watermark_width - $padding;
$dest_y = $image_size[1] - $watermark_height - $padding;
imagecopymerge($name, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, $opacity);
```

That var_dump() thing in the code always return `bool(flase)`

Can anyone give any hint why it is behaving so. Thank you in advacne.

Comment: You do not have the permissions to access that file

Comment: I just checked that directory is given a permission `755` changing it to 777 also returns the same warning

Comment: It should most likely be chown www-data:www-data

Comment: Then what should I do to make it work as I have already wasted plenty of time solving this issue and as a last option posted it here

Comment: you need to change the owner of the file, not permissions, so use command `chown`

Comment: Sorry Sir, I didn't get it when you say change owner of the file as I am admin and these files are uploaded by me so I think I am the owner of these files

Comment: You might be the owner of the file, but the web server(apache,nginx) uses the www-data user to read files and if the file owner is you(root) the www-data user might not be able to read that file

Comment: OK right let me try this as well

Comment: are you sure `$link = get_the_permalink();` returns the url of the image?

Comment: Yes it is giving me url in the following format `"https://www.example.com/p/4877/product_name/"`

Comment: ՝'https://www.example.com/p/4877/product_name/'՝ is not the image url. you should look at [imagecreatefromjpeg function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code you can add watermark for your images,

//path to destination image

```
$destination_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('PATH/TO/DESTINATION/JPEG/FILE');
```

//path to watermark image

```
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('PATH/TO/WATERMARK/PNG/FILE');
```

//calculate center position of watermark image

```
$watermark_left = (DST_IMAGE_WIDTH/2)-(WATERMARK_WIDTH/2); //watermark left
$watermark_bottom = (DST_IMAGE_HEIGHT/2)-(WATERMARK_HEIGHT/2); //watermark bottom
```

//use PHP imagecopy() to merge two images.

```
imagecopy($destination_image, $watermark, $watermark_left, $watermark_bottom, 0, 0, WATERMARK_WIDTH, WATERMARK_HEIGHT); //merge image
```

Source - https://www.sanwebe.com/2014/08/watermark-an-uploaded-image-with-php

Comment: Mam I am following the same solution but the issue is that the function `imagecreatefrompng('PATH/TO/WATERMARK/PNG/FILE')` is not working in my case it gives me this warning that I have posted in my question

Comment: And seondly I don't want the image watermark I want text waterwark on those images